# Symfony HWIOAuthBundle get user events and likes from facebook

Tags: facebook, symfony, scope, fosuserbundle, hwioauthbundle

I'm creating an app using FOSUserBundle and HWIOAuth bundle. The problem is that I cant figure out how to so I get information about the events user attended to  or other likes than "favorite_teams". I tried adding `user_events` to the scope but with no luck. I mean it asked me for additional permission about the events but when i var_dump the response I can't see any information about the events.

I've integrated HWIOAuthBundle with FOSUserBundle using this tutorial https://gist.github.com/danvbe/4476697

my scope in config is `scope: "email, public_profile, user_likes, publish_actions, user_events, user_groups, user_interests"`

and to be more exact all the info related to likes I get is favorite_teams no musicians nothing.

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is a good question - i am looking forward to the answer because i have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I integrated hwioauthBundle to connect with facebook and invit friends to join my web app(woops it's not authorized anymore in api 2) but first i used [graph api explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname&version=v2.3) to test facebook api and when i wanted call api in a controller i used [facebook php sdk](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4) and in my controller :

```
$user = $this->getUser();
if ($user && $accessToken = $user->getFacebookAccessToken())
{
    $session = new FacebookSession($accessToken);
    $session->setDefaultApplication($this->container->getParameter('facebook_client_id'), $this->container->getParameter('facebook_client_secret'));
    $friendsData = (new FacebookRequest(
          $session, 'GET', '/me/friends'
        ))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();
}
```

I hope it help.